# PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType() returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I am trying to get parent Method of a PsiElement. I get null by using the PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType method.

```
PsiMethod m = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(psiElement, PsiClass.class);
```

But it works when I iterate through the tree :

```
PsiMethod m;
while(true){
    psiElement = psiElement.getParent();
    try{
        m = (PsiMethod)psiElement ;
        break;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain me why PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType gives null while by iterating it doesn't give null and I get required result?

Comment: You want a `PsiMethod` but you're looking for a `PsiClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this and it works now.

```
PsiMethod s = PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(x, PsiMethod.class, false);
```

Comment: You said you wanted a `PsiMethod` but now you're getting a `PsiClass`?